# Android Listview scroll with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android

I am develop a small app which is display the image with timeline like this "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.carousel&hl=en":

Picture:

[image]

When user scrolls A, app should programmatically scroll B and vice versa.

here was my layout:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" >

    </ListView>

    <com.example.carousel_test.widget.HorizontalListView
      android:id="@+id/hl"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#ddd"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is the HorizontalScrollView inside the ListView or the ListView inside the HorizontalScrollView? It will help if you post your layout xml file.

Comment: use viewpager rather horizontalscrollview to achieve this